# Django ModelAdmin. Динамическая настройка админки

Tags: django, django-admin

Хочу, что бы в админке форма выглядела по-разному для разных экземпляром одной модели. Сделал так:

```
class PayForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        instance = kwargs.get('instance')
        if instance:
            PayAdmin.readonly_fields = (<поля>)
        else:
            PayAdmin.readonly_fields = (<другие поля>)

@admin.register(OrderPayment)
class PayAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PayForm
    ***
```

И это работает!
Но есть нюанс. Это работает с глюками, которые не сразу обнаруживаются. Иногда возникают ошибки при создании экземпляра, которые, впрочем, сами и исправляются. Что-то типа 'обращение к несуществующим полям формы'. При первом нажатии - ошибка. При повторном - нормально.
Какие еще могут быть варианты решения?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 158, in __getitem__
    field = self.fields[name]
KeyError: 'order'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 188, in render
    return template.render(context)
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 173, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 165, in render
    values = list(values)
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/helpers.py", line 113, in __iter__
    yield AdminField(self.form, field, is_first=(i == 0))
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/helpers.py", line 125, in __init__
    self.field = form[field]  # A django.forms.BoundField instance
  File "/home/str/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 164, in __getitem__
    ', '.join(sorted(self.fields)),
KeyError: "Key 'order' not found in 'OrderPaymentForm'. Choices are: ."
```

Comment: Если такое возможно, приведите трейсбэк ошибок

Comment: привожу трейсбэк. OrderPayment - это собственно модель.

Answer (score 1):

вообще достаточно странно ты это реализовываешь. Т.е у тебя ModelAdmin создает форму с одним списком полей для чтения, потом в форме ты меняешь у ModelAdmin список полей для чтения, получается какая-то круговая зависимость.

Для этих целей у ModelAdmin есть метод [get_readonly_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_readonly_fields)

```
def get_readonly_fields(request, obj=None)
    if obj:
        return (<поля>)
    return  (<другие поля>)
```